# analyze systemd journal of a crashed / dead system

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

i resently upgraded a system. after reboot i was not able to login again. all users have been rejected with `Login incorrect`. systemd with journaling was running and writing error messages to file in `/var/log/journal` as usual.

i so booted a system from a revovery usb stick (same distribution) mounted the root device of the failed system /mnt and tried to analyze the logs with `journalctl --root=/mnt/var/log/journal -xe`. journalctl did not find journal files.

question: how can i read systemd journal content of a dead system using a recovery system?

have fun

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late, but I stumbled upon this question and here is what I found:
`journalctl` logs are located in `/var/log/journal/*` 
`journalctl` app can read foreign journal files with the following switches:

- `--file=` followed by the *.journal file of your choice. This option may be used multiples times
- `--root=` followed by the root directory of you choice, probably a mounted partition
- `--image=` followed by a disk image,

files as argument, with the option `--file`